# php recursive - directory names to appear as headings

Tags: php, recursion, directory

I wish to list all directories and subdirectories in a folder as an un-ordered list. 

Found the code below that makes the correct list. But i need help with two things:

```
<?php
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

listFolderFiles('../targetfolder');

?>
```

---

All the directory names should appear as headings, like so:

```
<li> <h2> directory name </h2> <li>
```

and sub directory names, like so:

```
<li> <h3> sub directory name </h3> </li>
```

---

Inside the target directory, there are two main directories. Their names should not appear in the list -

I have very limited experience with php :)
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
  static $level = 0;
  $level++;
  $ffs = scandir($dir);
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach($ffs as $ff){
    if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
      echo '<li>';
      if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
        $h_start = ($level == 1) ? '<h2>' : '<h3>';
        $h_close = ($level == 1) ? '</h2>' : '</h3>';
        echo $h_start.$ff.$h_close;
        listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
      } else {
        echo $ff;
      }
      echo '</li>';
    }
  }
  echo '</ul>';
  $level--;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this works very well. I also needed help with the second thing in my question - i need to hide the main folder names in the target folder. The list should only have the sub directories and their sub directories

Comment: put `echo $h_start.$ff.$h_close;` inside an `if ( ... )` condition, where you check whether `$ff` is `in_array` of `excluded directories array`

Comment: Shall try it out. if i need to add another h tag for another level of the subdirectory, can i just add `code $h_start = ($level == 1) ? '<h2>' : '<h3>' : '<h4>'; `  Will that be a correct way to write it?

Comment: then just use `$h_start = "<h".($level+1).">";`

Comment: if there are sub-directories at depth `8`, i don't know how `<h9>` might end up looking on the browser. It might be too small. So better use `$h_start = ($level < 5) ? "<h".($level+1).">" : "<h5>";`.

Comment: Thanks. tried level+1 but directory names and directory contents - everything becomes a heading. Whereas i'm hoping to have only the directory/sub directory names as headings.

Comment: try `$h_start = ($level < 4) ? "<h".($level+1).">" : "<h4>";`

Comment: Sorry that gives the same result. All the files also get listed as headings.

Comment: Yes, i am making the same changes to _close also :)

Comment: `code <?php

function listFolderFiles($dir){
  static $level = 0;
  $level++;
  $ffs = scandir($dir);
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach($ffs as $ff){
    if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
      echo '<li>';
      if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
        $h_start = ($level < 4) ? "<h".($level+1).">" : "<h4>"; 
        $h_close = ($level < 4) ? "<h".($level+1).">" : "<h4>"; 
        echo $h_start.$ff.$h_close;
        listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
      } else {
        echo $ff;
      }
      echo '</li>';
    }
  }
  echo '</ul>';
  $level--;
}

listFolderFiles('../targetfolder');

?>`

Comment: For `$h_close` use `</h` instead of `<h`. Note the `forward slash`.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much air4x :) It was silly oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
                echo '<h3>' . $ff . '</h3>';
                listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            }
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

echo '<h2>folder</h2>';
listFolderFiles('folder');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple and hackable solution :

```
function dir2ul($path,$title,$n){
    if(!is_dir($path))return "<a href=\"$path\">$title</a>";
    $html="";
    foreach(preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($path)) as $file)
        $html.='<li>'.dir2ul($path.'/'.$file,$file,$n+1).'</li>';
    return "<h$n>$title</h$n><ul>$html</ul>";
}
echo dir2ul('page','',1);
```